# Unit testing DB repositoty class under lots of static helpers

Tags: unit-testing, static, microsoft-fakes

I started to work on partially finished MVC web-project and my task now - to cover code by unit tests. Project has DB storage and non-static Repository class containing CRUD operations. To test these CRUD operations I need to mock real Repository class with FakeRepository, so I created IRepository and used IoC to inject it...

But the problem is that project also has a lot of static classes with a lot of static methods (Helpers) that extends basic CRUD operations and all controllers in app works with these static helpers, which internally creates the Repository class...

Tried to modify all static methods to pass IRepository from controllers, but there are toooo much helpers based on other static helpers and so on... It doesn't work! I have no time to rewrite all this mess...

So I need and advice how can I test all these helpers, but with fake IRepository instance?

Comment: Which version and edition of Visual Studio are you using? Do you have access to VS2012 Fakes?

Comment: Visual Studio 2012. Yes, I have access to fakes, but AFAIK it is not possible to fake static class...

Answer (score 0):

[You can create s Shim (from Microsoft Fakes) to override the behavior of a static method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx#shims).

The code will look something like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass1
{ 
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestCurrentYear()
        {
            int fixedYear = 2000;

            // Shims can be used only in a ShimsContext:
            using (ShimsContext.Create())
            {
              // Arrange:
                // Shim DateTime.Now to return a fixed date:
                System.Fakes.ShimDateTime.NowGet = 
                () =>
                { return new DateTime(fixedYear, 1, 1); };

                // Instantiate the component under test:
                var componentUnderTest = new MyComponent();

              // Act:
                int year = componentUnderTest.GetTheCurrentYear();

              // Assert: 
                // This will always be true if the component is working:
                Assert.AreEqual(fixedYear, year);
            }
        }
}
```